# How to start java programm in this scenario?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation, javac

Im trying to open a java file where I reference an other java file.
Setup as follows:
I have classes A, B and C like the following:

class A:

```
package proj;

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

class B:

```
package proj;
public class B {
    C c;
}
```

class C:

```
package proj;
public class C {
    B b;
}
```

When I try to type in terminal `javac A.java`, an error occurrs (see below). Same when I try  `javac B.java` or `javac C.java`. How can I start my java programm?

[image]

error:

```
Desktop\test\proj> javac A.java
A.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        B b = new B();
        ^
symbol:   class B
location: class A
A.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        B b = new B();
                ^
symbol:   class B
location: class A
2 errors
```

Comment: `javac A.java B.java C.java`? (And note that this isn't _starting_ the program, it's just compiling it).

Comment: @AndyTurner OMG that worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *compile* the set of files – A.java, B.java, and C.java – by [using `javac` and a wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/javac.html#example-of-compiling-multiple-source-files), like this:

```
javac *.java
```

To *run* (or "start") your program, you would use `java` to [start the Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1), followed by whatever classes or jars you want to run in the JVM.

Here's a section in the Java Tutorial which includes examples for [compiling and running in Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html), and a similar example for [Mac, Linux and Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/unix.html).